# process text file in r to get two vectors

Tags: r

I have a text file whose format is like following:

```
groupA, 123
groupA, 32
groupB, 222
groupA, 212
groupB, 213
...
```

How can I easily form two vectors `[123, 32, 212, ...]` and `[222, 213, ...]` for groupA and groupB each?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `split`. This will result in a named list with each list item being one of your vectors.

```
mydf <- read.csv(header = FALSE, text = "groupA, 123
groupA, 32
groupB, 222
groupA, 212
groupB, 213")
mydf2 <- split(mydf$V2, mydf$V1)
mydf2
# $groupA
# [1] 123  32 212
# 
# $groupB
# [1] 222 213
```

If you don't want a `list` (though I find it preferable to having lots of single vector objects in my workspace), you can use `lapply` and `assign`:

```
## Verify that there are no objects currently named `groupA` or `groupB`
ls(pattern = "group")
# character(0)

## Assign each list item to a new object, making use of the `names` of the list
invisible(lapply(names(mydf2), 
                 function(x) assign(x, mydf2[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv)))

## Verify the presence and values of the new vectors
ls(pattern = "group")
# [1] "groupA" "groupB"
groupA
# [1] 123  32 212
groupB
# [1] 222 213
```

Answer (score 0):

Ananda Mahto's answer is more versatile (and interesting!), but here's a simple sub-setting method that also gets the two vectors:

```
mydf <- read.csv(header = FALSE, text = "groupA, 123
groupA, 32
groupB, 222
groupA, 212
groupB, 213")

# the dataframe is automatically assigned
# column names V1 and V2...

# vector of V2 for groupA
mydf[mydf$V1 == "groupA",]$V2
[1] 123  32 212

# vector of V2 for groupB
mydf[mydf$V1 == "groupB",]$V2
[1] 222 213
```